Need to enable memory mapped mode using standard SPI
I'm using NUCLEO-U575ZI-Q board. I want to enable the memory mapped mode for the external flash memory connected to it. I know it is possible with QSPI and OSPI interfaces, but the end device doesn't support the QSPI and OSPI. It only supports standard SPI mode. Can anyone help me how can I enable the memory mapped mode using the standard SPI interface?
I have established the communication between the ST board and the flash memory with the standard SPI mode. But now I'm stuck in to enable the memory mapped mode.

You should add details about memory chip in use. Do you mean it's a standard AT25xxx or compatible?
